# Booting Windows 7 from different SATA controller

Tags: windows-7, boot, sata, windows-7-restore

I have a Win7 installation on a box where the on-board SATA controller died, so I've added a dedicated controller card, and now need to fix the Windows boot sequence that the driver is loaded with the first batch.

The easy way using Startup Repair has failed, claiming the first time that the problem is solved, and that it cannot find any problem ever since.

Is there a command in the Startup Repair system that will allow me to add a driver to the boot drivers in an existing installation?

Comment: Please clarify, had you managed to configure your computer to boot from the new controls and just need to fix the boot loader sequence? Or is the problem is booting from a disk on the new controls?

Comment: The BIOS loads the Windows boot loader properly, but switching to the Windows drivers fails as the appropriate driver for the new controller is not installed. Startup Repair allows me to load a driver (which allows me to access the installation) but apparently does not install the driver in a way that will allow the boot to continue after deactivating the BIOS.

Comment: Any updates? thinking of doing something similar before my on-board SATA controller dies completely... Just went through full Win8 re-install and don't feel like doing it again.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across the same problem and after a while of searching found http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/513343/changing-controller-on-an-existing-but-offline-windows-7-64-installation/

> Hi
>   It is possible if you have the unpacked Windows 7 driver files of
>   the current storage controller. What you need to do is to boot from
>   the "Windows 7" setup DVD, System repair CD or from a "WinPE 3.0" and
>   use the DISM command to inject the storage controller driver . You
>   will find more info in the below links.
>   christian.hofstaedtler.name/blog/2013/01/using-dism-to-add-drivers.html
>   forums.overclockersclub.com/?showtopic=192550

The linked page led me to:

> Install Microsoft/Generic Storage Drivers This includes MSAHCI,
>   IntelIDE, AMDIDE, ATAPI, PCIIDE and so on:
>
> dism /image:d:\ /add-driver /driver:d:\windows\inf\mshdc.inf
>   /forceunsigned (D: is assumed to be the Windows SystemDrive
>   partition.)
>
> Install LSI MegaRAID / SAS/SATA Drivers dism /image:d:\ /add-driver
>   /driver:d:\windows\inf\megaraid.inf /forceunsigned (D: is assumed to
>   be the Windows SystemDrive partition.)
>
> Install VirtIO Storage Drivers If you have the VirtIO drivers ISO
>   mounted, and added the drivers in the Recovery GUI, dism can add them
>   to the offline Windows as well:
>
> dism /image:c:\ /add-driver /driver:d:\win7\amd64\viostor.inf (C: is
>   assumed to be the Windows SystemDrive partition, and D: is the virtio
>   ISO/CD.)

which is exactly what I needed.  I used the installation DVD to load into Windows Recovery then loaded the PCIe SATA driver that was missing from a USB.  Once it loaded, I was able to attempt recovery which either failed or succeeded but then I opened up command prompt from the options that were available and ran the dism command to install the driver from the USB drive onto the hard drive.